# Using OMP parallel to add to count in for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, count, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to speed up some processing with OMP parallel

but the cnt value is different every time, it's not adding across all for some reason. thanks.

```
        RGBTRIPLE rgb;
        COLORREF color;
        int cnt = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for private(color, rgb) shared(cnt)
        for(short ii=0;ii<cx;ii = ii + 1) 
        {
            for(short j=0;j<cy;j = j + 1)
            {
                color = pDC->GetPixel(ii,j);


                rgb.rgbtRed = GetRValue(color);
                rgb.rgbtGreen = GetGValue(color);
                rgb.rgbtBlue = GetBValue(color);
                if(rgb.rgbtRed>0 && rgb.rgbtRed<255) 
                {
#pragma omp critical
                    cnt++;
                    //TRACE("color: %d,%d,%d\n",rgb.rgbtRed,rgb.rgbtGreen,rgb.rgbtBlue);
                }
            }
        }



#pragma omp single
        {}

        CString msg; msg.Format("%d done",cnt);
        AfxMessageBox(msg);
    }
```

Comment: Are `GetPixel(ii,j)` and `GetR/G/B/Value` functions threadsafe? Use `reduction(+:cnt)` instead of `shared(cnt)` and `#pragma omp critical`. Define your variables in the minimum required scope. `#pragma omp single` has no effect as it is outside the parallel region.

Comment: Please do not use `GetPixel` but buffered operation. `GetPixel` is known to be very slow. In fact, regarding your GPU vendors (GDI is implemented by GPU vendors like Nvidia, AMD or Intel), I think it may cause a CPU-GPU transfer and using multiple threads will certainly not help to speed up that (It will instead saturate your PCI bus in a very inefficient way and slow down your machine for no reason).